# Binding to window.navigator.getUserMedia

Tags: ffi, reason, bucklescript

`[@bs.module] external navigator: unit = "window.navigator";`

giving following error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'window.navigator'`

How to access the windows.navigator in ReasonML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.navigator` is not a module, but a "global value", so you should use `@bs.val` instead:

```
[@bs.val] external navigator: unit = "window.navigator";
```

See the documentation on how to [Bind to Global Values](https://bucklescript.github.io/docs/en/bind-to-global-values) for more details.